# Kotlin Coroutine SupervisorJob canceling behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

code:

```
viewModelScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
                Log.e("TAG", "task 1")
            }) {
                try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 1 start")
                    delay(3000)
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 1 finished")
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 1 cancelled " + ex)
                }
            }

    launch = viewModelScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
        Log.e("TAG", "handler 1" + myJob?.isCancelled)
    }) {

        myJob = SupervisorJob()
        launch(myJob!! + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
            Log.e("TAG", "handler 2 " + myJob?.isCancelled)
        }) {

            delay(300)
            launch {
                try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 start")
                    delay(5000)
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 finished")
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 ex " + ex)
                }
            }

            launch {
                delay(2000)
                throw Exception()
            }

        }

        launch {
            try {
                Log.e("TAG", "task 3 start")
                delay(3000)
                Log.e("TAG", "task 3 finished")
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e("TAG", "task 3 ex " + ex)
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
2020-01-06 09:47:56.462 7159-7159/? E/TAG: task 1 start
2020-01-06 09:47:56.496 7159-7159/? E/TAG: task 3 start
2020-01-06 09:47:56.798 7159-7159/com.mvvm.template.debug E/TAG: task 2 start
2020-01-06 09:47:58.822 7159-7159/com.mvvm.template.debug E/TAG: task 2 ex kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling; job=StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@81a8e39
2020-01-06 09:47:58.827 7159-7159/com.mvvm.template.debug E/TAG: handler 2 false
2020-01-06 09:47:59.464 7159-7159/com.mvvm.template.debug E/TAG: task 1 finished
2020-01-06 09:47:59.499 7159-7159/com.mvvm.template.debug E/TAG: task 3 finished
```

my issue:

I’m having an issue to understand why task 2 is canceled when it’s a child of SupervisorJob and the exception happened on an other child.

The documentation state:

A failure or cancellation of a child does not cause the supervisor job to fail and does not affect its other children, so a supervisor can implement a custom policy for handling failures of its children.
Am i missing something or what ? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is right there in the log:

```
task 2 ex kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling;
job=StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@81a8e39
```

Look at the parent job: it's a `StandaloneCoroutine` and not your `SupervisorJob`.

When you write

```
launch(myJob!!, handler) { ... }
```

`myJob` becomes the *parent* of the launched coroutine and the coroutine itself is always associated with a job the `launch` function creates for it, of the type `StandaloneCoroutine`. Inside this coroutine you launch more coroutines without explicitly specifying a parent, which means their parent is the coroutine's job. It is not a supervisor job and gets canceled.

Answer (score 2):

> I’m having an issue to understand why task 2 is canceled when it’s a child of SupervisorJob and the exception happened on an other child.

Here this is not a direct answer to the question as it's already answered well by the accepted answer as the parent is not the `SupervisorJob`

But in order to achieve the intended behavior of making task2 independent of the sibling jobs:

**You've to use `SupervisorJob` by either:**

1. Making the `SupervisorJob` the parent of each task that you want to be independent of one another:

In your example:

```
val myJob = SupervisorJob()
    val launch = viewModelScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
        Log.e("TAG", "handler 1" + myJob.isCancelled)
    }) {

        launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
            Log.e("TAG", "handler 2 " + myJob.isCancelled)
        }) {

            delay(300)
            launch(myJob) { // <<<<<<<<< myJob is the parent
                try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 start")
                    delay(5000)
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 finished")
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 ex $ex")
                }
            }

            launch(myJob) { // <<<<<<<<< myJob is the parent
                delay(2000)
                throw Exception()
            }

        }

        //......
    }
```

2. Add the child job siblings within a [`supervisorScope` suspend function](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html)

```
val launch = viewModelScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
    Log.e("TAG", "handler 1")
}) {
    launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
        Log.e("TAG", "handler 2 ")
    }) {

        delay(300)

        supervisorScope { /// <<<< supervisor scope
            launch {
                try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 start")
                    delay(5000)
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 finished")
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "task 2 ex $ex")
                }
            }

            launch {
                delay(2000)
                throw Exception()
            }
        }

    }

    //....
}
```

Now **task 2** will complete without raising `JobCancellationException`